# HttpContext.Current.Session["accesstoken"].ToString() is null when value should be set

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm setting my accesstoken retreived from facebook in Session["accesstoken"]. When I try to retreive it I get hit by a nullreferenceexception.

Why?

It did work before I started working on the AddAdditionalPermissions method but I cant see how this would interfere with Session...?

In debug mode I copied the value from result.ExtraData["accesstoken"] and added it to the code via formscollection(as you can see in Facebook.cs) and the token worked. Should I use a cookie instead?

AccountController.cs

> ```
>     public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
>     {
>         AuthenticationResult result =   
>         OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(
>                 Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback",
>                 new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
>         if (!result.IsSuccessful)
>         {
>             return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
>         }
>
>         // Save the accesstoken into session
>         Session["accesstoken"] = result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];
>         Session["id"] = result.ExtraData["id"];
>
>         if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
>         {
>             AddAdditionalPermissions();
>             return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
>         }(...etcetera)
> ```

AdditionalPermissions function:

> private void AddAdditionalPermissions()
>           {
>               string facebook_urlAuthorize_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
>               string facebook_urlGetToken_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
>               string facebook_AppID = "1secretappIdhere242341";
>               string facebook_AppSecret = "1secretcodeheteq4426";
>
> ```
>         string scope = "publish_stream"; 
>         string urlAuthorize = facebook_urlAuthorize_base;
>         urlAuthorize += "?client_id=" + facebook_AppID;
>         urlAuthorize += "&redirect_uri=" + "http://localhost:2730/";
>         urlAuthorize += "&scope=" + scope;
>
>         Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, true);             
>     }
> ```

Facebook.cs

> public void PostToFacebook(FormCollection fm)
>           {
>               var fb = new FacebookClient();
>
> ```
>         fb = new FacebookClient(HttpContext.Current.Session["accesstoken"].ToString());
>         var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
>         args["message"] = "abc";
>
>         fb.Post("/me/feed", args);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your session token cookie being lost. Try not terminating current page response, by replacing

```
Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, true);
```

with

```
Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, false);
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks RAS. While it solves the Session problem it wont redirect user to be prompted for additional permissions. I.e. destroys the functionality.

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson, what if you execute: HttpApplication.CompleteRequest() right after Response.Redirect. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Tried that, no change. What I did do was to make a work around by setting a cookie which worked while working with this yesterday. Today I started up and the cookie behaves just like my Session. Could it be IISExpress thats bugging out?